# SVN Missing file, will it be removed from Version control after commit?

Tags: svn

I deleted two files from my project in xCode.

When I do a `svn status` in the terminal I get the `!   filename.file`
I know that this means that the file is missing but is still under version control, my question is will it be removed from version control after my next commit? Or is there a command I have to run to remove these files from version control manually.

Also in the future, is there a command to remove the file from version control from the terminal which will also delete it from my xCode project?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`commit` does not delete your missed file.

To mark it as scheduled for deletion you need to run `svn delete file` ([see doc](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.delete.html))